# How to set a env for perl 5.36 binary in linux

Tags: perl, rhel

We have RHEL 8.6 server and the perl is by default installed when we installed the RHEL. PERL version is 5.8.9. we need to install PERL 5.36. so we are trying to install the same. downloaded PERL binary from https://www.perl.org/

we executed

```bash
sh <(curl -q https://platform.activestate.com/dl/cli/_pdli01/install.sh)
state activate --default saravraj-org/Perl-5.36.0-Linux-CentOS
```

Also

```bash
sh <(curl -q https://platform.activestate.com/dl/cli/_pdli01/install.sh) \
   -c'state activate --default saravraj-org/Perl-5.36.0-Linux-CentOS'
```

Now the perl -v command shows the version as 5.36

```
build@sarav~/Perl-5.36.0-Linux-CentOS ❯❯❯ perl -v | grep 'This is'
This is perl 5, version 36, subversion 0 (v5.36.0) built for x86_64-linux
```

when we execute OpenSSL configure its taking perl 5.8.9 version still
so we need to set the env for perl 5.36 version.

could you please provide the setpes for the same.

build@sarav /a/m/p/o/a/ciscossl-1.1.1n.7.2.390 ❯❯❯ perl -v ✘ 1

This is perl 5, version 36, subversion 0 (**v5.36.0**) built for x86_64-linux

Copyright 1987-2022, Larry Wall
build@sarav /a/m/p/o/a/ciscossl-1.1.1n.7.2.390 ❯❯❯ ./config --prefix=/auto/open/linux/openssl no-threads no-ecdh no-ec -
fPIC
Operating system: x86_64-whatever-linux2
**Perl v5.10.0 required--this is only v5.8.9**, stopped at ./Configure line 12.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./Configure line 12.
Perl v5.10.0 required--this is only v5.8.9, stopped at ./Configure line 12.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./Configure line 12.
This system (linux-x86_64) is not supported. See file INSTALL for details.

we are expecting the script to take the PERL 5.36 version but it's taking 5.8.9

Comment: Where did you get the ssl `config` script from? Please provide a link so we can download and test. Which version of SSL is this?

Answer (score 0):

You might also use `perlbrew` for installing and setting the default Perl on your system conveniently.

https://perlbrew.pl/

> To install the latest stable release, and use it as default in the current shell and in all future shell sessions.

```
perlbrew install perl-5.36.0
perlbrew switch perl-5.36.0
```